# Powershell script that finds and changes hyperlinks in word saves doc and creates a new copy as PDF

Tags: powershell

I am trying to figure out how to write a script that goes through a folder and grabs all word documents in the folder to search for a hyperlink and change the link to another link. Then to save that word document as well as create another version of it converting it to a pdf.

How can I adjust the script below to grab all word documents in a folder then search all hyperlinks for "https://www.yahoo.com" to "https://www.google.com". Some how looping through the entire document searching through ALL hyperlinks. Saving that document and then converting and giving a new pdf.

Is this possible?

**What I have so far**

```
    $word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
        $document = $word.documents.open("path to folder")
        $hyperlinks = @($document.Hyperlinks) 
        $hyperlinks | ForEach {
            $newURI = ([uri]$_.address).AbsoluteUri
            Write-Verbose ("Updating {0} to {1}" -f $_.Address,$newURI) -Verbose
            $_.address = $newURI
        }
        If (_$.address -eq "https://www.yahoo.com/") {
            $_.Address = "https://www.google.com/"
        } ElseIf ($_.Address -eq "http://def.com/motorists") {
            $_.Address = "http://hij.com/"
        }
        $document.save()
        $word.quit()

    Get-ChildItem -Path $document -Include *.doc, *.docx -Recurse |
        ForEach-Object {
            $doc = $word.Documents.Open($_.Fullname)
            $pdf = $_.FullName -replace $_.Extension, '.pdf'
            $doc.ExportAsFixedFormat($pdf,17)
            $doc.Close()
        }
    $word.Quit()
```

I am new to powershell will someone please help walk me through these steps. I hear powershell is probably the best and strongest language to get this sort of thing accomplished.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hadn't done this before, so it was nice to figure it out. We both get to learn today! You were very close. Just needed a few adjustments and a loop for handling multiple files. I'm sure someone more knowledgeable will drop in but this should get you the desired result.

```
$NewDomain1 = "google"
$NewDomain2 = "hij"
$OurDocuments = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Apps\testing" -Filter "*.doc*" -Recurse

$Word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$Word.Visible = $false

$OurDocuments | ForEach-Object {
    $Document = $Word.documents.open($_.FullName)
    "Processing file: {0}" -f $Document.FullName
    $Document.Hyperlinks | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Address -like "https://www.yahoo.com/*") {
            $NewAddress = $_.Address -Replace "yahoo","google"
            "Updating {0} to {1}" -f $_.Address,$NewAddress
            $_.Address = $_.TextToDisplay = $NewAddress
        } elseif ($_.Address -like "http://def.com/*") {
            $NewAddress = $_.Address -Replace "def","hij"
            "Updating {0} to {1}" -f $_.Address,$NewAddress
            $_.Address = $_.TextToDisplay = $NewAddress
        }
    }

    "Saving changes to {0}" -f $Document.Fullname
    $Document.Save()    

    $Pdf = $Document.FullName -replace $_.Extension, '.pdf'
    "Saving document {0} as PDF {1}" -f $Document.Fullname,$Pdf
    $Document.ExportAsFixedFormat($Pdf,17)

    "Completed processing {0} `r`n" -f $Document.Fullname
    $Document.Close()
}

$Word.Quit()
```

Let's walk through it...

We'll first move your new addresses into a couple of variables for ease of referencing and changing in the future. You can also add the addresses that you're looking for here, replacing the hard-coded strings as needed. The third line uses a filter to grab all .DOC and .DOCX files in the directory, which we'll use to iterate over. Personally, I would be careful using the `-Recurse` switch, as you run the risk of making unintended changes to a file deeper in the directory structure.

```
$NewAddress1 = "https://www.google.com/"
$NewAddress2 = "http://hij.com/"
$OurDocuments = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Apps\testing" -Filter "*.doc*" -Recurse
```

Instantiate our Word Com Object and keep it hidden from view.

```
$Word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$Word.Visible = $false
```

Stepping into our `ForEach-Object` loop...

For each document that we gathered in `$OurDocuments`, we open it and pipe any hyperlinks into another `ForEach-Object`, where we check the value of the `Address` property. If there's a match that we want, we update the property with the new value. You'll notice that we're also updating the `TextToDisplay` property. This is the text that you see in the document, as opposed to `Address` which controls where the hyperlink actually goes.

This... `$_.Address = $_.TextToDisplay = $NewAddress1` ...is an example of multi-variable assignment. Since `Address` and `TextToDisplay` will be set to the same value, we'll assign them at the same time.

```
$Document = $Word.documents.open($_.FullName)
"Processing file: {0}" -f $Document.FullName
$Document.Hyperlinks | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Address -like "https://www.yahoo.com/*") {
        $NewAddress = $_.Address -Replace "yahoo","google"
        "Updating {0} to {1}" -f $_.Address,$NewAddress
        $_.Address = $_.TextToDisplay = $NewAddress
    } elseif ($_.Address -like "http://def.com/*") {
        $NewAddress = $_.Address -Replace "def","hij"
        "Updating {0} to {1}" -f $_.Address,$NewAddress
        $_.Address = $_.TextToDisplay = $NewAddress
    }
}
```

Save any changes made...

```
"Saving changes to {0}" -f $Document.Fullname
$Document.Save()
```

Here we create the new filename for when we save as a PDF. Notice `$_.Extension` in our first line. We switch to using the pipeline object for referencing the file extension since the current pipeline object is still the file info object from our `Get-ChildItem`. Since the `$Document` object doesn't have an extension property, you'd have to do some slicing of the file name to achieve the same result.

```
$Pdf = $Document.FullName -replace $_.Extension, '.pdf'
"Saving document {0} as PDF {1}" -f $Document.Fullname,$Pdf
$Document.ExportAsFixedFormat($Pdf,17)
```

Close the document up and the loop will move to the next file in `$OurDocuments`.

```
"Completed processing {0} `r`n" -f $Document.Fullname
$Document.Close()
```

Once we run through all documents, we close Word.

```
$Word.Quit()
```

I hope that all makes sense!

Comment: this is so super close except that I am trying to do a search a replace on only part of a link making the rest of the link stay the same.

Comment: Just updating the TLD, then? Easy enough to do. You're essentially doing something like `$NewAddress = $OldAddress -Replace "yahoo","google"`. Assuming all other parts of the address can stay the same, that is. I'll try to toss that into the answer in a moment.

Comment: Changes made and they're working for my tests. `$_.Address -eq` is now `$_.Address -like` with an asterisk at the end of the string, so that we find any links starting with those. `$NewAddress = $_.Address -Replace "yahoo","google"` generates the new address by replacing _only_ the domain name. Should be easy enough to adjust those as needed to get the searches just right for your files.