# PowerShell won't iterate through a document

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

A PowerShell script won't iterate through a document to change each hyperlink in the document.

The script runs through a document library on SharePoint online and can open each document in the library. Then it should iterate through each document and pull any hyperlinks that it finds and then split the hyperlink into two parts. The script should then add the second half onto a new URL and update the Address to be the new, updated URL.

```
add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word"
$wdunits = “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdunits” -as [type]
$donotsave = “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdDoNotSaveChanges” -as [type]
$save = “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdSaveChanges” -as [type]

$application = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$application.Visible = $false

$tenancy = "https://tenancy.sharepoint.com"
$url = "https://tenancy.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -UseWebLogin

$library = Get-PnPList | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq "libraryName"}
$items = Get-PnPListItem -List $library
foreach ($item in $items) {
    if ($item["FileLeafRef"] -match ".doc*") {
        Write-Host "File Name: "$item["FileLeafRef"]
        $item["FileLeafRef"]
        $item["FileRef"]
        Write-Host `

        $documentLocation = "https://tenancy.sharepoint.com"+$item["FileRef"]
        $documentLocation

        $document = $application.Documents.Open($documentLocation)

        $docURLS = @($document.Hyperlinks)

        $docURLS | foreach{
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 7
            $newURI = ([uri]$_.address).AbsoluteUri
            $result = $newURI.Split("=") | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1
            $result
            $newUrl = "https://tenancy.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID="+$result
            $_.address = $newUrl 
            Write-Verbose ("Updating {0} to {1}" -f $_.Address,$newUrl) -Verbose 
        }
        $document.save()
        $document.close([Ref]$save)
       $item.File.Update()    
    }
}

$application.quit()
Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

The script can currently iterate through the library and open each document, the issue comes when there are multiple hyperlinks in the document. 
It changes the first URL correctly, but every other link after that receives the following errors:

> Object has been deleted.
>   At C:\filepath.ps1 :36 char:5
>   +     $_.address = $newUrl
>
> The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED))
>   At C:\filepath.ps1:39 char:9
>   +         $document.save()
>
> The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED))
>   At C:\filepath.ps1:40 char:9
>   +         $document.close([Ref]$save)
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>   At C:\filepath.ps1:33 char:5
>   +     $result = $newURI.Split("=") | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1

Comment: Please never use curly 'smart-quotes' in code. They may look nice in Word documents, but they can ruin your code. Why do you split the $newUrl in such a difficult manner? You can simply do `$result = ($newURI.Split("=", 2))[1]` to get the part after the `=`.

Comment: Hi @Theo I changed the $result as you mentioned, thank you I didn't know you could do that :) I've only recently started with PowerShell. What do you mean about curly smart-quotes? Do you know I would be able to resolve my issue at all? Thank you

Comment: The curly quotes are on the definition of `$wdunits`, `$donotsave` and `$save`. You can see the difference with normal straight quotes. As for errors, I think your code `$document.close([Ref]$save)` is wrong and should be `$document.close()`, See [Document.Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.close(method))

Comment: @Theo Okay thank you I see the difference. Upon changing to $document.close() I know receive the error: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component at the line $_.Address = $newUrl. I don't understand how to solve this error, do you have any advice?

Comment: Are you getting anything with `$newURI = ([uri]$_.address).AbsoluteUri` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell script that finds and changes hyperlinks in word saves doc and creates a new copy as PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46412951/powershell-script-that-finds-and-changes-hyperlinks-in-word-saves-doc-and-create)

Comment: Hi @Theo, when I try to declare $newURI in the console window I get nothing, then get an error when trying to split the URL: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Comment: `$docURLS | foreach` --> `$docURLS | ForEach-Object {..}`

Comment: Hi @Theo, I changed the start of the foreach loop as you suggested. Now the script can iterate through each of the links, however I receive the error:  Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component at the line $_.Address = $newUrl.

Answer (score 0):

If the $_.address value like "/sites/team?ID=1", the $newURI will null, then run $newURI.Split("=") | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1 will get "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression".

You can check if the $newURI is null before use $newURI.Split method.

Or we can replace the code below.

```
$newURI = ([uri]$_.address).AbsoluteUri
$result = $newURI.Split("=") | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1
```

with

```
if($_.Address)
{   
    $result = $_.Address.Split("=") | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1
}
else
{
    $_
}
```

Comment: Hi @LZ_MSFT thanks for getting back to me :) I changed my code with your suggestion and I now receive the error: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression at the line '$result = $_.address.Split("=") | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1'. But I'm not sure why it is null

Comment: using if($_.Address) to check if the value is null, then run the split method. Check the updated reply above.

Comment: Hi @LZ_MSFT I have made the above change to the code and I now receive the error of: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component at the line $_.Address = $newUrl

Comment: Did you modify the code like if($_.Address)
{   
    $result = $_.Address.Split("=") | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1
}
else
{
    $_
} ?

Comment: Yes I did change it to if($_.Address) { $result = $_.Address.Split("=") | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1 } else { $_ }